# Why is $\mathbb{R}^2$ not a subset and /or a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

One thing this suggests--at least to me--is that the x-y plane and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are not necessarily equivalent.  For example, I could define the following: $X = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} x,y \in \mathbb{R} \land z = 0\right\}$.  Am I wrong to think, one, that this is a *subset* of $\mathbb{R}^3$?  As I write this it occurs to me that while scalar multiplication is closed under the above rules, addition doesn't pass the smell test for a subspace... so, OK, it's certainly not a subspace.  I would welcome any insight readers of this query can provide.

Comment: What is true is that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. For instance via $(x,y)\longmapsto (x,y,0)$.

Comment: what kind of equivalence are you looking for ? it is certainly equivalent as a vector space (and also as a topological vector space)

Comment: What you wrote is in fact a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, namely the $x$-$y$ plane, and it is _isomorphic_ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (just not _equal_, as Asaf points out.)

Comment: Appreciate the clarifications -- implication for me is that we *can* arbitrarily constrain $z = 0$, even under addition.  I guess that's obvious, but I wasn't sure: thanks, again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The elements of $\Bbb R^2$ are vectors of **two** coordinates; and the elements of $\Bbb R^3$ are vectors of **three** coordinates. (One can easily think of those vectors as $2$-tuples and $3$-tuples, for example.)

Assuming mathematics is consistent, $2\neq 3$. Therefore no element of $\Bbb R^2$ is an element of $\Bbb R^3$. It follows that $\Bbb R^2$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R^3$.

And in order to be a subspace, one first has to be a subset. So it's not a subspace either.

---

What you have defined as $X$ is *isomorphic* to $\Bbb R^2$, but just as well you could decide that $y$ is $0$, and the identification would still be natural. $X$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^3$ and indeed a subspace, but it is not $\Bbb R^2$ as a set, it is just isomorphic to it in a very obvious way.

While isomorphism is an equivalence relation, and we often think of it almost as identity, it is still not *set equality* which is a stricter notion.

Comment: Thanks very much -- I'm beginning to see the light.

Comment: Uhh, that's a train. You're standing on the tracks. :-)

Answer (score -3):

Assume $m<n.$  Then on the standard basis, $\mathbb{R}^m$ is, in fact a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n.$

**The vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$:**
Begin by defining $\mathbb{R}^n$ (and similarly for $\mathbb{R}^m,$ etc.,) as the $n^{th}$ Cartesian product of $\mathbb{R}.$  Doing so requires an ability to distinguish each $\mathbb{R}$ appearing as a Cartesian factor from the others.  For example, in $\mathbb{R}^3$ we distinguish each by calling them the $x,y,z$ axes.  We  nominate each factor using a subscript natural number $i=1 \dots i=n$ so $\mathbb{R}^n=\mathbb{R}_1\times\dots\times\mathbb{R}_n,$ and assume the natural ordering on the indices.  These designations are arbitrary.  We could choose any unique subscript values in any ordering, just so long as we distinguish each Cartesian factor $\mathbb{R}$ from the others.

**The standard basis $\left\{\mathfrak{\hat{e}}_i\right\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n:$**
From each $\mathbb{R}_i$ we identify its real number $1\in\mathbb{R}_i$ with the symbol $\mathfrak{\hat{e}}_i\in\mathbb{R}_i.$  The $\mathfrak{\hat{e}}_i$ are called the elements (vectors) of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n.$  The set $\left\{\mathfrak{\hat{e}}_i\right\}$ is linearly independent, and spans $\mathbb{R}^n$.  That is, every element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given as a unique linear combination of the standard basis vectors.

**$\mathbb{R}^m$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$:** We construct $\mathbb{R}^m$ and its standard basis $\left\{\mathfrak{\hat{f}}_j\right\}$ using the same method with $j=1 \dots j=m<n.$  The next natural step is to identify $\left\{\mathbb{R}_i=\mathbb{R}_{j=i\le{m}}\right\}$ which gives $\left\{\mathfrak{\hat{f}}_j=\mathfrak{\hat{e}}_{j=i\le{m}}\right\}.$

**Therefore, assumming standard definitions and natural identities, $\mathbb{R}^m\subset\mathbb{R}^n.$**

Of course, we could use different definitions, leading to different results.  For example, a typical definition is $\mathbb{R}^{n-m}=\mathbb{R}_{i=m+1}\times\dots\times\mathbb{R}_n.$
Other than an appeal to sanity, there is nothing to stop us from identifying $\mathbb{R}^{p}=\mathbb{R}^{n-m},$ where $p=n-m,$ and $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ is constructed as above.  Indeed $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ are isomorphic, so there is an equivalence relation between them.

Comment: You have explained why there is a natural-ish embedding $\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$. For the reason explained in the other answer, this is not the same as set equality. Like I said in the question you asked, please do not use SE to expound your personal views, do that on your personal blog.

Comment: The most primitive definition of a basis vector is an identifiable object which is linearly independent of other basis vectors under consideration.  This linear independence is attributed by definition.  As such, basis vectors have no "internal structure".  They have no intrinsic dimensionality.  The set of all linear combinations $\mathfrak{\hat{e}}_{1}r^{1}+\mathfrak{\hat{e}}_{2}r^{2}$ constitutes $\mathbb{R}^2,$ and is a uniquely defined subset of $\mathbb{R}^3.$